# Lipschitz Functions and Cauchy Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

I need help with a particular question:

A function $f(x)$ is Lipschitz on $\mathbb R$ if $\exists C$ that is a constant such that $\forall x, y \in \mathbb R,|f(x)-f(y)| \leq C|x-y|$.
Show that if $f$ is Lipschitz on $\mathbb R$, and if $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then $(f(x_n))$ is also Cauchy.

We are required to show that $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists K \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall x_n, x_m > K, |f(x_n)-f(x_m)| < \varepsilon$.

Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists K' \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n, m > K', |x_n-x_m| < \varepsilon$.

---

*What could be right/wrong.*

Since $f$ is Lipschitz, would it imply that $f(x_n)$ is Lipschitz? 
If it is, then we have $|f(x_n)-f(x_m)| \leq C|x_n-x_m|$.

and thus $\frac{|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|}{C} \leq |x_n-x_m|$.

Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, then $\frac{|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|}{C} \leq |x_n-x_m| < \varepsilon$ and
 $\frac{|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|}{C} < \varepsilon$.

Comment: You're using the same $\,K\,$ for two things that require different ones...

Comment: Let me change the $K$ then. Sorry!

Comment: More is in fact true: A Lipschitz function is uniformly continuous and a uniformly continuous function maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\{x_n\}\;\;\text{Cauchy means}\;\; \forall\;\epsilon>0\;\exists\;N_\epsilon\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\;n,m>N_\epsilon\Longrightarrow |x_n-x_m|<\frac{\epsilon}{K}$$

so now, again for $\,n,m>N_\epsilon\,$ :

$$|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|<K|x_n-x_m|<K\frac{\epsilon}{K}=\epsilon$$

Comment: Should that $L$ be replaced by $K$?:)

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is Lipschitz, there exists $K>0$ such that for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|.$$ We now show that $(f(x_n))$ is Cauchy. Let $\epsilon >0.$ Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $m,n\ge N$, we have $$|x_n-x_m|<\frac{\epsilon}{K}.$$ Therefore, for any $m,n\ge N$ (here it is clear that $x_n,x_m\in \mathbb{R}$), we get $$|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|\leq K|x_n-x_m|<K\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{K}=\epsilon.$$ We are done.